# Synchronizing files in Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am new to Emacs and I am not very good with computing. However I discovered Emacs few weeks ago and I am absolutely amazed with possibilities that it has. I am looking forward  to use it for LaTeX documents editing, some programing, creating my own elisp functions and of course creating plans and notes with org-mode. The main inconvenience for me is that I am using Emacs at several places  (my laptop, home and work computers). At work I am unauthorized to install software. If i make some changes in my .emacs file or to-do list I need it to be synchronized everywhere. I am using dropbox but it is a bit annoying because at work I need to download it overwrite older one and etc.  I need some practical advice on how can I synchronize some private files, that changes made in one place could be quickly loaded in other place.

P.S. sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: *I am using dropbox but it is a bit annoying because at work I need to download it overwrite older one and etc* Could you explain again what's wrong with just using dropbox? If you use dropbox correctly, it should automatically synchronize your folders at home and at work.

Comment: I cannot install dropbox at work, use it only online.

Comment: So your question has very little to do with Emacs, really. What you are asking is how to sync some files between home and work. Your constraints—inability to install any software at work—rule out most standard solutions, such as dropbox or `git`. Maybe you should ask the question at superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs is portable by design. There is no dependencies to any platform specific feature.

So, in theory, the problem you describe here boils down to a pure file synchronization problem. And if I got it right the real limitation are the corporate constraints imposed by your company.

I assume that DropBox is tedious to use because you are not allowed to use the application that created the full integration abut that you are limited ot the Web Interface... if this is the case, you may be restricted the same way for all other alternatives.

One option that I suggest in these environments is to install Emacs, or at least your .emacs folder on a USB stick (I like the micro USB sticks that looks like a mouse dongle and is hardly noticeable).

You'll be able to use emacs anywhere, and if you are concerned about backups, you can always implement a manual or automated backup solution on one of the other machine you are using and where you have more access rights.

Comment: Use of USB sticks are restricted in my office.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dropbox for sure, but you might also want to check [SugarSync](http://sugarsync.com) since it allows the option of sharing ANY file on your computer with any other device (and is also accessible online on their website).

My structure is like this:

I have a sugarsynced folder "school" where I have my LaTeX files (and pdf's) and R files that are shared. I make my homework, and in class I usually read my pdf's from my phone. Everything syncs automatically.

For my Emacs files, I use Dropbox: the good thing is that at other computers you can just make sure it looks exactly at the same folders.

You generally would like a structure as:

**.../Dropbox/Emacs/.emacs**

In my .emacs, you define all load-paths and requires, such as:

```
 (let ((base "/Username/Dropbox/emacs/.emacs.d/"))
  (add-to-list 'load-path base)
  (dolist (f (directory-files base))
    (let ((name (concat base "/" f)))
      (when (and (file-directory-p name) 
                 (not (equal f ".."))
                 (not (equal f ".")))
        (add-to-list 'load-path name)))))
```

You should also set a customization file:

```
(setq custom-file "/path-to-dropbox/.emacs.d/emacs-custom.el")
(load custom-file)
```

and store backups in a folder:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "/path-to-dropbox/.emacs.d/backups")))
```

I would suggest such a structure:

```
emacs-display.el    (any visual stuff)
macros.el
misc-functions.el
external-plugins.el  (file for loading external packages and adjusts settings)
keybindings.el  (all your keybbindings)
```

You also set mode association for loading your personal file, for example for LaTeX:

```
(eval-after-load 'latex '(load "/path-to-dropbox/.emacs.d/personal-emacs-latex"))
```

In this you can put all the customization for whenever you are using LaTeX.

**.../Dropbox/Emacs/.emacs.d**

In this folder the actual files stored. It becomes really easy to remove something when it wouldn't work for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the tasks and events with org-mode, one option is synchronization with the Toodledo server -- there are Toodledo applications for most of the popular mobile computing devices.  The library is located at the following link:

https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo

I have modified the `org-toodledo` library to make it behave more like Toodledo, and in my `.emacs` file, I use:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '(
  (sequence
  "Active(a)"
  "Next Action(n)"
  "Canceled(c)"
  "Hold(h)"
  "Reference(r)"
  "Delegated(d)"
  "Waiting(w)"
  "Postponed(P)"
  "Someday(s)"
  "Planning(p)"
  "|"
  "None(N)") ))

(setq org-toodledo-status-to-org-map '(
    ("Active" . "Active")
    ("Next Action" . "Next Action")
    ("Reference" . "Reference")
    ("Delegated" . "Delegated")
    ("Waiting" . "Waiting")
    ("Someday" . "Someday")
    ("Planning" . "Planning")
    ("None" . "None")
    ("Hold" . "Hold")
    ("Postponed" . "Postponed")
    ("Canceled" . "Canceled") ))
```

In addition, wherever `"DONE"` is mentioned in the `org-toodledo` library, I changed it to `"None"` -- which I use for completed tasks / events.

I also modified another area of the code so that I can have five (5) priorities just like Toodledo.