# Limiting todo-keywords returned from Org-mode's built-in weekly/daily agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Using Emacs Org-mode synchronised with Toodledo I have the variable `org-todo-keywords` set to

```
((sequence "TODO" "NEXT" "|" "DONE")
 (sequence "WAITING" "HOLD" "SOMEDAY" "|" "CANCELLED"))
```

When want the built-in agenda view *weekly/daily agenda* by typing `C-c a a` I get all task that is not in the todo state `DONE`.

**How can I set Org-mode making the command `C-c a a` only return tasks of todo states `TODO` and `NEXT`?**

Of cause I can make a custom agenda view but I guess there is a variable that limits the todo states or an other simple way of modifying org-mode setting the built-in agenda view to fulfil my needs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On semi-related issues, to take full advantage of Toodledo, perhaps consider using the keywords for which Toodledo was intended:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22521109/2112489  Other things you may be interested in the future (**someday**, because you stated that you want just the stock behavior for now) include a custom agenda view, and a custom 12-month and 3-month calendar designed around Toodledo synchronization:  https://github.com/lawlist/lawlist-org  and   https://github.com/lawlist/calendar-yearly-scroll-by-month

Comment: And here is a link to Toodledo org-mode capture templates:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22384000/2112489 -- just in case **someday** you might be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just one solution -- there are others:

```
(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "regular expression")
```

http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html

see also

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html

---

Other settings that include filtering out completed tasks for deadline and scheduled are as follows:

```lisp
(org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)

(org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done t)
```

---

**EDIT** (April 26, 2014):  Included working example:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
  ("1" "Events" agenda "my-calendar" (
    (org-agenda-span 365)
    (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil)
    (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline))
    (org-agenda-skip-function
      '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "\\* TODO\\|\\* NEXT"))
    (org-deadline-warning-days 0)  ))))
```

Comment: So I might write something like
`(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "TODO|NEXT")`?

What other solutions are there?

Comment: @user3571637 -- I'm happy to give it a try tomorrow morning, but I'm away from the computer this evening and only have a hand-held device available.  Normally, regexp in Emacs is written like this:  `"TODO\\|NEXT"`.  I've never tried it your proposed way of writing it.  And, *yes*, that goes inside the settings of `org-agenda-custom-commands`.

Comment: @user3571637 -- You can also develop an `org-agenda-skip-function` that focuses on `org-todo-keywords`.  In a daily / weekly / monthly / yearly agenda view based on deadlines or scheduled, I don't think there is a default variable / setting to search for specific `org-agenda-keywords`.  So another method of doing what you want to accomplish would be to create an `org-agenda-skip-function` that uses something like `org-element-at-point . . .` with an `org-back-to-heading t` . . . -- however, the `(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "TODO\\|NEXT")` should work for your initial tests.

Comment: @user3571637 -- I've updated my answer with a working example -- just substitute your preferred keywords.  The example assumes you have at least one asterisk preceding the keyword.

Comment: @user3571637 -- And, here is an example that excludes anything matching a particular regexp:  `(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'regexp "\\* Active\\|\\* Next Action"))`

Comment: I think this does the wrong thing if child nodes have TODO or NEXT keywords — how can you modify this to handle that case?

Comment: @avv -- please consider launching a new question at http://www.emacs.stackexchange.com